# Sharepoint REST query - All files with last modified time greater than

Tags: rest

I am trying to get all the files including in the subfolders that have last modified time greater than a given timestamp.

The one thing I figured is that to get all files and subfolders, I need to use the following query and the $filter doesnt work with it. Any help please?

```
"/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Folders,Files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply filters when you use that endpoint by add `/Files` like this:

```
mysharepointsiteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/relativesiteurl/Documents')/Files?$filter=TimeLastModified gt datetime'2015-11-1T00:00:00'
```

But you can also just use the standard list endpoint and that's a bit easier:

```
mysharepointsiteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=Modified gt datetime'2015-11-1T00:00:00'
```

If you'd like to get all folders and files (including those within subfolders) then you will need to use CAML and specify the View **Scope** as **RecursiveAll**:

```
mysharepointsiteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/getitems(query=@q1)?@q1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-30' /></Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>"}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. One thing I would like is to get all the folders as well. Is there a way to do that

Comment: Sorry. This doesnt work. It only gives the files within the top level directtory. I would like to get all the files within all the top level and all the sub directories. Prefer a solution that gives me all the files and folders.

Comment: @MKay Gotcha, I've added the rest endpoint using CAML that will take care of this.

Comment: Thanks So much. This is so helpful and I really appreciate it.